# Conditional statement not working as expected

Tags: linux, shell, conditional-statements, konsole

I am using Konsole on kubuntu 14.04.

I want to take arguments to this shell-script, and pass it to a command. The code is basically an infinite loop, and I want one of the arguments to the inner command to be increased once every 3 iterations of the loop. Ignoring the actual details, here's a gist of my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
ct=0
begin=$1
while :
    do
        echo "give: $begin as argument to the command"
        #actual command
        ct=$((ct+1))
        if [ $ct%3==0 ]; then
            begin=$(($begin+1))
        fi
    done
```

I am expecting the `begin` variable to be increased every 3 iterations, but it is increasing in the every iteration of the loop. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to test with

```
if [ $(expr $cr % 3) = 0 ]; then ...
```

because this

```
[ $ct%3==0 ]
```

tests whether the string `$ct%3==0`, after parameter substitution, is not empty. A good way for understanding this is reading the manual for `test` and look at the semantics when it is given 1, 2, 3 or more arguments. In your original script, it only sees one argument, in mine it sees three. White space is very important in the shell. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In BASH you can completely utilize `((...))` and refactor your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ct=0
begin="$1"
while :
do
   echo "give: $begin as argument to the command"
   #actual command
  (( ct++ % 3 == 0)) && (( begin++ ))
done
```

Comment: I know, but even after writing #!/bin/bash, I think it's not using bash. That's why I used ct=$((ct+1)), which is the only one from http://askubuntu.com/questions/385528/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-bash that works.